# add library path in .htaccess file codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, mongodb

I am working on project with Codeigniter and MongoDB.
As there are no cheap hosting for MongoDB, i am using [MongoLab](https://mongolab.com/) where i am getting free MongoDB space and i hosted the project on other server. MongoLab Provides connection string to database with a port so right now i am connecting the MongoDB from my localhost with threadsafe `.dll` file and for that i have made changes `php.ini`.

As i hosted on shared server, when i contacted the customer support, they said that we can add library via `.htaccess` file as well.

I googled a lot but i have no luck with it.

So my question is pretty simple, How to add the library with `.htaccess` file so that i will out the library in folder and register it in `.htaccess` file?

Answer (score 0):

you could try to add into your htaccess file something like:

```
<IfModule mod_php5.c>
    php_extension_dir <path_to_php_extensions>
    php_extension <extension_name>.so
</IfModule>
```

Comment: This is something i required.
Right now i am on windows with xampp

I wrote following code but no luck with it


`<IfModule mod_php5.c>
    php_extension_dir "E:/xampp/htdocs/myproject/libraries"
    php_extension "php_mongo.dll"
</IfModule>`

I tired this with `"` and without `"`, I also tried `php_extension="php_mongo.dll"` something like this. But no luck.

Answer (score 0):

Your best option is to add a line in your php.ini file that references to that extension you installed.

```
extension=mongo.dll
```